# .net core razor page @Html.Displayfor showing a random number

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using .net core (.net 5) to create a calculator.
Here's my model:

```
   public class VogelsRulePlusModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0,30)]
    public double SpherePower { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(-30,0)]
    public double CylinderPower { get; set; }

    
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

To display the output of the calculation, I'm using the the following tag "helper"

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Result" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Result)</label>
        </div>
```

For some reason, when the page renders, I get a random number.
Here's the html this tag "helper" creates:

```
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Result">6.00</label> <-- ??
        </div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to make it stop?

UPDATE: I'm such a doofus...again, I had the wrong controller in here.
This is what I'm using for the view.

```
    public IActionResult VogelsRulePlus(VogelsRulePlusModel baseCurve)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        baseCurve.Result = BaseCurve.VogelsRulePlus(baseCurve.SpherePower, baseCurve.CylinderPower);
        return View(baseCurve);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your action,I don't know what data you pass to the view?

Comment: @YiyiYou I added the action as you requested.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Result)` will give you the value of `Result`. What is the value of you result before the view is returned?

Comment: If this action is GET, also verify you are not seeing a cached page.

Comment: `BaseCurve.VogelsRulePlus(baseCurve.SpherePower, baseCurve.CylinderPower);`what is `BaseCurve.VogelsRulePlus`,the result is depended on your `baseCurve` which is returned to  the view.

Comment: @Jasen I don't have a value for Result. When the page renders, it puts a "random" number as the Result.

Comment: Do you mean `baseCurve.Result = BaseCurve.VogelsRulePlus(baseCurve.SpherePower, baseCurve.CylinderPower);` didn't set the value of Result?If so,why you need to use it.And if you debug the code,`baseCurve.Result` is default value 0.00?